# Domain look up in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my asp.net application I want to use the look up domain information (ie WHOIS information).  When a user enters any domain name it has to look up and display the information.  Is there any code library or script I can use to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/DataScraping.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The only DNS library I've found is [DnDns](http://dndns.codeplex.com/) - I haven't had a call to use it though, so I don't know how useful it is.